Remote work from Israel
I am a US citizen, happily employed by a US-based company, currently spending a year in Israel on a A/4 "Family of clergy/student" visa.  My company does not do any business in Israel, would not hire someone in Israel, and I do not have any intent on working for Israeli companies on the side.
What are my obligations regarding getting a "right to work" permit/visa from Israel? Am I good as-is, do I have to switch to a B/1 work visa, or is there something else in between?  Does length of time in Israel matter?  I know that for practical purposes, I can just keep working remotely and no one is likely to care, but I'd like to know how I'm officially supposed to go about doing this.

A/4 is not allowed to work in Israel by default (doesn't matter where the employer is), but you can request a work permit as part of your application.
It can be given "at the discretion of the minister" (i.e.: some bureaucrat at the Ministry of Interior). The process is described here (this is a site for a Jewish organization, I don't know whether proof of Jewishness is actually required - check with the consulate). With that you can become self-employed and become a contractor for your US employer. You'll need to deal with all the taxes and social security issues, of course, and learn the concept of VAT.
B/1 is a foreign employee visa, and requires an Israeli employer sponsoring you which doesn't sound like something you'd be interested in.
You should probably discuss your options with a local immigration attorney.

I know that for practical purposes, I can just keep working remotely and no one is likely to care

Yes, until someone does. A nosy neighbor, or you get into some issue related to your work (like a job-related injury), or someone decides to screw your employer (having an employee in Israel opens the employer to a huge liability). There's also a tax information exchange between the US and Israel.

That sounds like it pretty much covers it.  I would still have to change my employment status with my employer, though?

@user30660 yes, probably

But does OP actually considered to "working in Israel" given the remote nature of their work?

@einpoklum the remote is relative to the employer, not relative to Israel. The work is in Israel, and that's what matters.

@einpoklum Literally the reason why remote working and digital nomad visas were invented.

@Traveller interesting website. After reviewing their article about the US, I can only assume it can not be relied upon to tell the color of the sun, let alone immigration policies of multiple countries. Typical "I'm a digital nomad, laws don't apply to me" mentality.

@littleadv I agree, their advice on UK immigration rules on remote working as a visitor is unreliable too.
